# Jolt Transformation to match on multiple key values

Tags: jolt

I'm struggling to find the correct jolt spec to evaluate the values of two keys prior to creating an output. Any ideas?

Input:

```
{
  "ticketInformation": {
    "area": "001",
    "site": "ABC",
    "ticketType": "TC"
  }
}
```

Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ticketInformation": {
        "area": {
          "001": {
            "#Works": "OneMatch"
          }
        },
        "ticketType": {
          "TC": {
            "#OnlyEvaluatingTicketType": "HowToEvalueValuesOfTwoKeys"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```

Output:

```
{
  "OneMatch" : "Works",
  "HowToEvalueValuesOfTwoKeys" : "OnlyEvaluatingTicketType"
}
```

The desired output is the same as the actual output but ONLY if area=001 AND troubleType=TC.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your ask?

Comment: Sure.  What I'm trying determine is how to have the spec to match on more than one item.  In my example above I get an output of  "OneMatch": "Works" if area is "001" and I get an output of "HowToEvalueValuesOfTwoKeys" : "OnlyEvaluatingTicketType" when ticketType is "TC".....I want to know how to have the spec evaluate the area=001 AND ticketType is "TC" and if both match write my output.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the spec you are looking for

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ticketInformation": {
        "area": {
          "001": {
            "@(2,ticketType)": {
              "TC": {
                "#Yes": "BothMatching"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```